# How to add pagination in Angular for a table?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, pagination

I am new to Angular and would appreciate if someone could help me add pagination to a table.
I created a CRUD project, where the backend was done in Spring boot and the frontend in Angular.
To do the layout I would like to use bootstrap directly, without going to create the specific code in springboot for the layout, then work directly in Angular.
I've seen some online, but couldn't find a simple thing in my case.
This is my html code related to the table of interest:

```js
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Students</h1><br>

    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="filterTerm">
    </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>Student code</th>
          <th>Student name</th>
          <th>Student date</th>
          <th>Action</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let student of students| filter:filterTerm">
          <td>{{student.codestudent}}</td>
          <td>{{student.namestudent}}</td>
          <td>{{student.datestudent}}</td>
          <td><button (click)="deleteStudent(student.codestudent)" class='btn btn-primary'><i
                class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>
            </td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody><br>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Can anyone kindly help me? I thank you infinitely.

Comment: One option you have to write a logic as dividing your total records by post per page and some other stuffs. 2nd you can use Data Tables which will provide pagination, sorting, live search. Have a [look](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you planning for client-side pagination or a server-side? This is not clear above!

If client-side: As you're already using `Bootstrap` Library, I recommend checking this for a quick and easy solution: `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/pagination/`, but do not use this for a large data set (definition of `large ds` is debatable, let's say `< 3000` records for the fields you mentioned in the code).

If server-side: Spring Boot can't do anything by itself, but the `ORM` like `Hibernate` or an `ODM` for `NoSQL` databases like `MongoDB`.

For example: `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL` will do the trick with `...offset().limit()` whereas `MongoDB` will do this with `...skip().limit()`. You need to create an API with a `GET` request with `parameters` (easier to bookmark on the browser). These parameters' number goes inside the above methods to create Pagination. Call this API on click on each page number or when the `First`, `Previous`, `Next` and `Last` buttons are pressed on the UI!

Please check the respective DB docs for more information.

Comment: I was saying directly on the client side. In spring boot it seems more complex, right? I am new, so it is difficult for me. Unfortunately, I don't have a clear idea of which path to take.

Comment: For the client side, the link I've provided you from the official documentation will serve the purpose. Just copy-paste the code and follow their short instructions to make it work. If it works for you, please accept this answer or comment if needed more help!